# Is 1/n gradually approaching 0 when n approaches infinity.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, harmonic-functions, divergent-series, geometric-series

According to the definition of **Convergent series**, "the series is said to be Convergent when **n** approaches infinite **a**n=L, where L is a constant." And when we prove that n/(n+1) will approach 1, we convert it to 1/(1+1/n) because 1/n will gradually approach 0. But in the P series, when P=1, it is a divergent (I know its proof process). Isn't the nth item here close to 0? Does this mean that I have any misunderstandings about the definition of convergent series. Or is the definition of harmonic series not applicable to general conversion series?

Thanks

Comment: This is something I tell my calculus students: For a series to converge, the terms must get small enough quickly enough.

Comment: Can you clarify *But in the P series, when P=1, it is divergent (I know its proof process).*? This is not clear at least for me.

Comment: @SeanRoberson ... And all the difficulty is to precise what both *enough* mean ;-)

Comment: @SeanRoberson  What I mean is that in the Harmonic series, we say that the speed at which 1/n approaches 0 is not fast enough, so we do not view it as convergent. However, when proving the limit of n/(n+1), we say that 1/n approaches to zero. Is this contradictory?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I just want to say Harmonic series, what do you think is unclear?

Comment: You just haven't define what P is...

Comment: You seem to confuse sequence and series.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net The definition of convergent sequence is' A sequence is said to be convergent if it approaches some limit '. My question is, if we believe that narrowing down is not fast enough to be considered as reaching the limit, why can we consider the limit of 1/n as 0 when we prove that n/(n+1) is close to 1. Does this has anything to do with the difference between sequence and series? In the definition of Convergent series, it is also written that when the nth term in the series approaches a constant, it does not involve a series is the sum of terms in a sequence

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147337/discussion-between-ili-a-and-mathcounterexamples-net).

Answer (score 5):

*Series* and *sequence* are synonyms in everyday English, but in math they have different meanings.

The sequence whose $n$th term is $\frac{1}{n}$ does in fact converge to zero. But the *series* whose $n$th term is $\frac{1}{n}$ is the same as the *sequence* whose $n$th term is $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$. That sequence does not converge, so the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ does not converge.

Because the phrases and notations around limits and sums are cumbersome, they often (unfortunately) get omitted in conversation. This can lead to some contradictory abbreviations:

- Because $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$, one might say “$\frac{1}{n}$ converges”. This is sloppy, but I think conventionally understood to mean the sequence converges.
- Because $\displaystyle\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n} = \infty$, one might be tempted to say “$\frac{1}{n}$ diverges.” You see the ambivalence, which is what brought you to this question.

Try to avoid these abbreviations, or each time you see them, get some clarity: “Do you mean the *sequence* $\frac{1}{n}$ or the *series* of the terms in that sequence?”

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid the phrasing "approaching" because there is nothing that moves. A limit is a number such that every neighborhood of it no matter how small it is contains all but finitely many members of the sequence. The distinction and the avoidance of the term approaching are important because a limit is a fixed certain number and nothing anything approaches.

A series is considered converging if its sequence of partial sums $$s_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$$ is convergent. So the term convergence is reduced to those of sequences, even in the case of series.